# EF Core - Join table without the joint field on each individual Entity

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a property on my entity `GroceryItem` called `GroceryItemGroceryStores` which exists for the sole purpose of letting Entity Framework Core know to create a join table. My other entity of the same join table `GroceryStore` has the same property. I don't actually want my two entities to have this property as it just leads to a never-ending cycle where a `GroceryItemGroceryStore` has an `Establishment (GroceryStore)` which has a `GroceryItemGroceryStore` which has the same `Establishment (GroceryStore)` and it continues forever. How do I delete the property `GroceryItemGroceryStores` from `GroceryItem` and `GroceryStore`, but keep the join table?
The entity having infinite depth:

[image]

```cs
namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    public class GroceryItem : AVeganItem<GroceryItemTag, GroceryStore>
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<GroceryStore> Establishments { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public virtual ICollection<GroceryItemGroceryStore> GroceryItemGroceryStores { get; set; }

    }
}

namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class AVeganItem<VeganItemTagType, EstablishmentType> : ADomainEntity<int>
    {
        [Required]
        public int IsNotVeganCount { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int IsVeganCount { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int RatingsCount { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public List<VeganItemTagType> Tags { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CurrentRevisionId { get; set; }

    }
}

namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class ADomainEntity<IdType>
    {
        public IdType Id { get; set; }

    }
}
namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public class GroceryStore : AEstablishment<GroceryItem>
    {
        public virtual ICollection<GroceryItemGroceryStore> GroceryItemGroceryStores { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is the join table. Just view its superclass. As you can see it has a few extra fields. Maybe that complicates things?

```cs
namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public class GroceryItemGroceryStore : AVeganItemEstablishment<GroceryItem, GroceryStore>
    {
    }
}
namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class AVeganItemEstablishment<VeganItemType, EstablishmentType> : ADomainEntity<int>
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0), Required]
        public int VeganItemId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1), Required]
        public int EstablishmentId { get; set; }

        public virtual VeganItemType VeganItem { get; set; }
        public virtual EstablishmentType Establishment { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int NotInEstablishmentCount { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int InEstablishmentCount { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public double Price { get; set; }

    }
}
```

database context:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<GroceryItemGroceryStore>()
            .HasOne(gigs => gigs.VeganItem)
            .WithMany(vi => vi.GroceryItemGroceryStores)
            .HasForeignKey(gigs => gigs.VeganItemId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<GroceryItemGroceryStore>()
            .HasOne(gigs => gigs.Establishment)
            .WithMany(e => e.GroceryItemGroceryStores)
            .HasForeignKey(gigs => gigs.EstablishmentId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<GroceryItemGroceryStore>(gigs =>
        {
            gigs.HasIndex(e => new { e.VeganItemId, e.EstablishmentId }).IsUnique();
        });
```

Comment: Which EF Core version are you using? Before EF Core 5, many-to-many relations *must* map the join table as well. With EF Core 5 the join table is [mapped automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#many-to-many)

Comment: Deleting a property isn't a fix to whatever problem you may have. What is the actual problem? How to map many-to-many? Or how to avoid circular references?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I’m on the latest version of EF Core. I would just like the GroceryItemGroceryStores field to be removed from the GroceryItem and GroceryStore objects.

Comment: Why? What's the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The fields don’t serve a purpose when dealing with the GroceryItem and GroceryStore objects so they are just polluting those objects with properties that will never be used

Comment: This is an inheritance problem then. The wrong base class was used for the join table. In fact, there's so much inheritance and non-standard naming involved in this question that it's hard to understand what class does what, or even what property you're talking about. The picture doesn't help at all. An ORM is meant to map relational tables to object entities. It's not a replacement for SQL or a proper database design. What is the join table supposed to contain? Just the foreign keys? Extra properties? Why use that base class ? Are you trying to implement table-per-class?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos all good then. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: You still haven't explained what the problem is, or what you actually want. Do you want extra properties in the join table or not? If not, don't use the base class. ORMs are called the [Vietnam of Computer Science](https://blog.codinghorror.com/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science/) because you can go only so far before the fundamental mismatch between OO and Relational models becomes too great. OO just can't cover the same design space. If the difference between DTOs and tables grows too big, mapping will be very hard

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when did I ever say I want to get rid of the extra properties in the join table? I have only ever said I want to get rid of GroceryItemGroceryStores from GroceryItem and GroceryStore because their only purpose is for creating a join table between GroceryItem and GroceryStore, so they pollute instances of those two classes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos inheritance is not the issue here. This issue would exist without inheritance. If all of my items will use a certain property then yes I will put that property in a superclass. I’ve stated the issue is pollution of my objects with properties they won’t use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework Core 5.0, you don't need to explicitly define a join table. EF Core will do it for you. You can define a collection of GroceryStore in GroceryItem Entity, and the GroceryItem entity can have a collection of GroceryStore entity. EF core will create a joining table for you.

For more details refer the link.
https://mycodingtips.com/2021/3/16/configure-many-to-many-relationships-in-entity-framework-core-code-first

Comment: Thanks, however since my join table has extra properties it does need to be defined explicitly.